# função que receba uma array de strings e retorne a quantidade de strings iniciadas pela letra "a"

Tags: javascript, array, string

estou com uma dúvida em uma questão que diz o seguinte:
escrever uma função que receba uma array de strings não vazias e retorne a quantidade de strings iniciadas pela letra "a".
Entrada: `[‘front-end’, ’angular’, ’back-end’, ’database’, ’async’]`

No caso eu fiz o código mas não sei retornar as strings (angular e async) onde a saída seria 2
Segue o código:

```js
const arr = ['front-end', 'angular', 'back-end', 'database', 'async'];

const getAmount = (array, value) => array.reduce((acc, item) => value === item ? acc + 1 : acc, 0);

console.log(getAmount(arr, 'a'));
```

Comment: olá se conseguiu fazer funcionar e alguma resposta te foi útil não esqueça de aceitá-la :)

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa usar [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para fazer isso, e a título de entender melhor sugiro usar o `forEach`, e também poderia ser simplesmente um `for`:

```js
const arr = ['front-end','angular','back-end','database','async'];
const total = getAmount(arr);

console.log(total);

function getAmount(arr) {
  var tot = 0;
  arr.forEach((palavra) => {
    if (palavra.toLowerCase().startsWith('a')) tot++;
  });
  return tot;
}
```

Note que no código usei [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) para converter para minúsculas, então se houvesse uma palavra como "Async" ela seria contada, isso é opcional.
A seguir usei [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) para saber se a palavra "começa por" a letra "a".

Answer (score 2):

Como já o foi dito o método [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) não é o método mais apropriado para realizar contagens.

Uma opção é fazer uma filtragem da entrada segundo um critério e contar o número de elementos que atenderam o determinado critério.
O método [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) retorna um array com todos os elementos que passaram no teste implementado por uma função fornecida como parâmetro.
O valor da propriedade [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) especifica o número de elementos em um array.

Como já foi dito o método [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) retorna o valor da string original convertido em letras maiúsculas e o método [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) determina se uma string começa com os caracteres especificados retornando um booleano.

A solução possui lógica é simples, apenas filtre os elementos do array de entrada que iniciam com a devida letra e pegue o número de elementos retornados pela filtragem.

```js
const arr = ['front-end', 'angular', 'back-end', 'database', 'async'];

const getAmount = (a, l) => (a.filter((s) => s.toUpperCase().startsWith(l.toUpperCase()))).length;

console.log(getAmount(arr, 'a'));
```

Comment: Acho que era pra ser `s.toLowerCase()`, não? Da forma que está, retorna `0`.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, faltou um colocar a letra em uppercase. Desculpem-me a noobicie. xD

Answer (score -3):

Nesse caso, você deve trabalhar com String Includes, pois ele irá observar em todo o texto se inclui o valor, seja uma letra, uma palavra ou o que for.
Segue um Exemplo:

```js
const words = ['front-end', 'angular', 'back-end', 'database', 'async'];

const findLetter = (arr, val) => arr.reduce((acc, item) => item.includes(val) ? acc + 1 : acc, 0);

findLetter(words, 'a')

//resultado: 4

findLetter(words, 'f')

//resultado: 1
```

Comment: O autor da pergunta quer apenas palavras iniciadas com a letra.